# Changing the locking object inside @synchronized section

Tags: objective-c, synchronization

Can I do any of the following? Will they properly lock/unlock the same object? Why or why not?  Assume there are many identical threads using global variable "obj", which was initialized before all threads started.

1.

```
@synchronized(obj) {
    [obj release];
    obj = nil;
}
```

2.

```
@synchronized(obj) {
    obj = [[NSObject new] autorelease];
}
```

Comment: Note: Related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1215330/

Comment: After reading this SO post, I decided to investigate @synchronized a little more thoroughly and write a blog post on it. You may find it useful: http://rykap.com/objective-c/2015/05/09/synchronized.html

Comment: @rjkaplan your link is broken

Comment: Aw, dang, thanks @RicardoAlves. Here's a working one: http://rykap.com/objective-c/2015/05/09/synchronized/


(Unfortunately I can't edit the comment above)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Short answer: no, they won't properly lock/unlock, and such approaches should be avoided.

My first question is why you'd want to do something like this, since these approaches nullify the purposes and benefits of using a @synchronized block in the first place.

In your second example, once a thread changes the value of `obj`, every subsequent thread that reaches the @synchronized block will synchronize on the new object, not the original object. For N threads, you'd be explicitly creating N autoreleased objects, and the runtime may create up to N recursive locks associated with those objects. Swapping out the object on which you synchronize within the critical section is a fundamental no-no of thread-safe concurrency. Don't do it. Ever. If multiple threads can safely access a block concurrently, just omit the @synchronized entirely.

In your first example, the results may be undefined, and certainly not what you want, either. If the runtime only uses the object pointer to find the associated lock, the code may run fine, but synchronizing on `nil` has no perceptible effect in my simple tests, so again you're using @synchronized in a pointless way, since it offers no protection whatsoever.

I'm honestly not trying to be harsh, since I figure you're probably just curious about the construct. I'm just wording this strongly to (hopefully) prevent you and others from writing code that is fatally flawed, especially if under the assumption that it synchronizes properly. Good luck!

Comment: In my particular case (the reason I found this Q/A) is that I want to do something like (sorry, no good formatting in comments)...  `@synchornized(obj) {  if (obj != nil) { ...[do stuff, snip]; obj = nil } }` (*NOTE: * I'm under ARC, so I get my `release` for free.  What I want is, if there's an obj, to sync it while I mess around.  If it's nil, I don't really care.