# is [_internal lock] in synthesized accessors the same as @synchronized(self)?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa

It's fairly well documented that @synthesize atomic settings/getters are implemented with "something" like so:

```
{
    [_internal lock]; // lock using an object-level lock
    id result = [[value retain] autorelease];
    [_internal unlock];
    return result;
}
```

The situation I have, I want to access two properties atomically (ie. not unlocking the lock inbetween), so my first instinct was to use @synchronized(self) - however I've been unable to find anything that says if @synchronized(self) uses the **same** lock as an atomic getter/setter. Does anyone know if they do?

Comment: Check the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1215330/how-does-synchronized-lock-unlock-in-objective-c

Comment: Thanks, that's certainly interesting background reading, but unless I missed it, it doesn't answer my question? It confirms that @syncronised doesn't use an NSLock, but I can't see a description of what atomic getters/setters use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the things Apple's docs are very good at, is specifying *exactly* what the contract is. In this case, [the relevant part of the docs](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocProperties.html) says only that it's locked using an object-level lock. Note that it doesn't say **which** lock it is, so you **cannot** assume it's the same locking mechanism as `@synchronized(self)`. (It may very well be not.)

Comment: Although that doesn't actually answer my question, it is a very polite way of pointing out that I'm asking the wrong question. As you say, what matters is whether I can rely on them being the same thing as Apple upgrades the OS, regardless of whether or not they're currently the same thing. Thanks!