# How does @synchronized work?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, multithreading

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does @synchronized lock/unlock in Objective-C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1215330/how-does-synchronized-lock-unlock-in-objective-c)

I have an application that creates several objects. Each of these objects is essentially running in a different thread, and operating on an `NSMutableArray` which is part of a separate class. There are several different methods in this class that enumerate and mutate the array, and as expected the multiple threads do not work well with this. I have tried surrounding all the method bodies in `@synchronized` blocks, as I read somewhere that that would lock the methods to one thread at a time, but it doesn't seem to have helped. How can I make sure that only one thread is accessing these methods at a time?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1215330/how-does-synchronized-lock-unlock-in-objective-c

Comment: Sorry, but I still dont really understand. Could you maybe point me to a resource where I can learn more about @synchronized?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can not tell this better than Apple. Take a look at section "Using the @synchronized Directive".  http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/ThreadSafety/ThreadSafety.html

Double-check that you are passing the same synchronization/lock object into synchronized so threads will not access the same section.

Comment: As far as I can tell, surrounding my method bodies in @synchronized should work. Am I missing something?

Comment: You are right. Are you sure that you surrounded all required parts of your code with @synchronized? Could you confirm that block has the same object that they are using for locking?

Comment: Hint: you can pass you array as a lock object.