# What's the best methods to use a singleton in different threads

Tags: ios, ios4

I am trying to build a singleton caching class . Now i am stuck with a problem that , When two threads simultaneously accessing the methods in my singlton what will happen , is it will crash . Means in my class i have some methods that reads and writes to files from disk. So what's the best methods to overcome this situations . I have to use Locks or Syncronised methods .... Helps me to understand the things ..

Comment: So...  Did you just answer your own question at the end there?

Comment: is i have to use Locks or Syncronised methods ? ... can anyone point me any examples ....

Comment: I would just use a lock around the underlying hash map.  Not sure on the specific code since I've never done any Objective C stuff.  Should be able to google for an example though.

Comment: This post may be of help in understanding @synchronized [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1215330/how-does-synchronized-lock-unlock-in-objective-c][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1215330/how-does-synchronized-lock-unlock-in-objective-c

Comment: Synchronized is slow, rather use OSAtomic: http://mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2011-03-04-a-tour-of-osatomic.html if you want to make sure something in the singleton runs only once at a time, or even better grand central dispatch queues

Answer (score 0):

Use `dispatch_once` to guarantee that the initialization will only happen the first time the method is called.

```
+ (NSArray *)foo
{
    static NSArray *_sharedFoo;
    static dispatch_once_t count = 0;

    dispatch_once(&count, ^{
        _sharedFoo = [[Foo alloc] init];
    });

    return _sharedFoo;
}
```

### EDIT

For more details about working with the dispatch API, see http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/Reference/reference.html