# How to lock a method when using multithreading?

Tags: iphone, ios, multithreading, ipad, nsthread

how can I stop 2nd thread to access same method that is being used by first thread?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to use @synchronized in the method.

```
- (NSString *)someMethod {
  @synchronized(self) {
      // do some work
  }
}
```

It allows the method to be called but will synchronize on itself and protect it's work (and more importantly the data it's working on).

Comment: It worked. Thank you. I still have a doubt. Once the process is completed by first thread, does the 2nd thread have access to this method automatically? Do all other threads wait until first thread completes it work?

Comment: Yes, both threads enter the method, one executes the synchronized block of code and when it does the other will continue execution.

Comment: Here's a deeper explanation on what it does:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1215330/how-does-synchronized-lock-unlock-in-objective-c

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at NSLock.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSLock_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Just found it when looking for a C# lock statement, it appears to do the same thing..

There is also another SO thread relating to synchronisation:

[How does @synchronized lock/unlock in Objective-C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1215330/how-does-synchronized-lock-unlock-in-objective-c)