# locking a managedObjectContext

Tags: ios, core-data, locking, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I'm currently on a (very) big application developed by something else.

It's well developed and the code looks pretty good... Instead of the access to core data.

Indeed, each access to `ManagedObjectContexts` are made in several blocks, corresponding to several web services... in several threads.

[And the documentation says it's bad](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdConcurrency.html). That's why sometimes, my app freeze on a Core Data access.

Yes, I know I should

> Create a separate managed object context for each thread and share a single persistent store coordinator

as the doc says, but the code already exists and it's very huge and my client need a solution quickly (as usual).

**So here's the question :**

I've seen a `[managedObjectContext lock]` method. It seems to be some semaphore stuff. But the doc doesn't speak a lot about.

My webservices, in different threads are using the same instance of the managedObjectContext.

-What do you think about doing

```
[managedObjectContext lock]
// core data access
// core data access
// core data access
[managedObjectContext unlock]
```

In each of my web services blocks ?
-Will this resolve the freezes ?
-Is it a recommended way ?

**Nobody told me about the `lock` & `unlock` methods, so I made an EDIT :**

Because de freezes do not occurs everytime, I tried 3 cases :

- Do not protect my data access
- Use `[managedObjectContext lock]` `unlock]` methods
- Use `@synchronized(managedObjectContext) { ... }`

In the first case, a freeze occured 3 times on 10 tests. In the 2nd and 3rd cases, no freeze at all.

**So my second question :**

What is the difference using `lock`/`unlock` and `@synchronize( )` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had a similiar problem, on existing code I didn't work directly, with blocks performing fetch on a single managed object context, ended up on weird error, freezing, thread exiting etc.

I solved by adding a sinchronize on context:

```
NSBlockOperation *myBlock = [NSBlockOperation blockOperationWithBlock:^{

  // block operation

  @synchronized(managedObjectContext) {

    NSArray *result = [managedObjectContext performFetch:myFetch];

   // error management following

  }
}];
```

this is the quickest solution I found. I also tried to add some sort of locking condition but threads were messing up and deadlocking in some cases.

Comment: thanks for your answer, I will try it tomorrow. The problem is that it's hard to reproduce the freeze and see if the problem is resolved.

Comment: Try to see this question, is quite complete, and I used to decide between two options: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1215330/how-does-synchronized-lock-unlock-in-objective-c/1215541#1215541

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what SDKs you need to run on, but if you can use iOS 5+ `-performBlock:` and `-performBlockAndWait:` may be just what you need.

Hope that helps.